# How to have core data restore the DB after deletion

Tags: swift, core-data

We have a process in our application that upon changing users we delete the contents of the documents directory.  One of the casualties is our core data sqlite database file and support.

To the question, does anyone know of a way to tell core data to replace that file in an empty state?

Comment: Restart the app will do it. But why do you have your persistent store in the Documents folder in the first place?

Comment: Yes, it. is recreated upon app startup.  If not in the documents folder, where would you recommend?

Comment: "Application Support", probably